# Como usar o WebHook do discord em sua plataforma

Tags: webhook, discord

O `Discord` tem um recurso para configuração de `WebHooks` para vincular com outras plataformas *(github por exemplo)*.

**Mas como esse recurso é usado?**

- O que eu posso enviar usando o WebHook?
- Qual a estrutura que os dados devem ser enviados?
- Como aplicar esse sua usabilidade a uma linguagem de programação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `WebHook` é um meio de comunicação entre aplicação, sua funcionalidade é semelhante uma `Rest APIs`.

A principal diferença em uso é que na `Rest Api` o cliente faz a solicitação das informações no servidor enquanto no `WebHook` o servidor envia as informações para o cliente para o mesmo processa-las.

Um caso comum de uso de `WebHooks` é feito em plataformas de pagamento, onde quando o pagamento é confirmado pala plataforma, ele dispara uma mensagem ao `endpoint` do cliente (ou servidor) com os dados de pagamento para o cliente consumir.

Mas falando expecificamente do *Discord*, seu `WebHook` é utilizado para a publicação de conteúdos nos canais.

Essa comunicação é feito a partir de um `JSON` que será enviado para o `endpoint` criado para o canal no discord.

```js
{
  "content": "Teste",
  "username": "MyUser",
  "embeds":[
    {
      "description": "teste webhook",
      "title": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

O `Json` acima é a estrutura básica para o envio dos dados para o `WebHook` do *Discord* e caso não ocorra erros o *Discord* retorna o código `204`.

Também é possível enviar *imagens*, *links*, *campos*, e outros tipos de dados assim como no exemplo a baixo.

```
{
  "embeds":[
    {
      "image": {
        "url": "image url"
      },
      "fields": [{
        "name": "Field Name"
        "value": "Field Value"
        "inline": true
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Para o disparo a partir de uma linguagem de programação pode usar uma requisição *https* e enviar um json junto dos dados.

```rb
require "net/https"
require "net/http"
require "json"

uri = URI("<Discord Webhook URL>")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).tap do |http_conf|
  http_conf.use_ssl = true
  http_conf.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path,
                          "Content-Type" => "application/json",
                         )
req.body = {
  content: "Teste",
  username: "MyUser",
  embeds:[
    {
      description: "teste webhook",
      title: "Test"
    }
  ]
}.to_json
res = http.request(req)

puts "#{res.body} #{res.code}"
```